# No Error Info in Microsoft.Websockets OnError event handler

Tags: asp.net, websocket

I can't get websockets over WCF working at all.

I am using the websocket samples from Paul Batum. (https://github.com/paulbatum/WebSocket-Samples)

I have a Windows 8 operating system, .Net 4.5 and IIS 8 with websockets enabled.
When I run the WCFChat project, what I always get is the onerror followed by the onclose event firing on the client and server.

The onerror event argument on the client doesn't provide any meaning diagnostic info. Using Fiddler does not provide any information, too.

The OnError event handler on the server is the same. There are not event arguments or any other way to see why OnError is being called. "Call Stack" only shows External Code calling OnError method.

The question is how can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]OK. I had to use WebSocketHandler class. WebSocketHandler has the Error property which I wanted to see.